# Send to all users with a specific language in Firebase Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the Firebase Console it is possible to target devices using a specific app, language, version and user properties. Is it somehow possible to do the same with the API? Or is creating topics the only way to solve bulk sending notifications?

Basically what I would like to do is send a notification to all users with a specific language. I would use the console, but I need to set a click_action / category and that's not supported in the console (as far as I know).

Comment: By the api as I read when I have a problem like yours the only answer that i have is to create a specific topic like "en-us" for exemple, but i dont know if now its possible to do that. if you use topic it Works fine.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way within the API to select devices that match arbitrary criteria.  You will have to figure out how to select the appropriate devices yourself.  You have two options

One strategy might be to use [topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple#about_topic_messaging) that match the languages that you might wish to target.  Client apps can subscribe to the topics that match their language preferences, and you can broadcast a message to them via those topics.

Another strategy might be to store language preferences for each user/device in your database (along with the device's token), then query for users/devices who have that language preference.  Once you've collected all the tokens for the matching devices, you can send a message using only those tokens.

Comment: That's what I assumed. I've created topics for each users locale. Too bad that the API and the console can't do the same thing.

Comment: The selections in the console are based off data collected by Analytics, and Analytics currently doesn't have a public API for accessing its data.  You can export your Analytics data to BigQuery to get a hold of it, but that's a capability beyond what can be provided without cost.

Comment: @DougStevenson: If we use topics, how do you take care the case that user switches their language? i.e. trigger unsubscribe topic. Thanks.